# How to increase/decrease reverse_iterator by any value using difference_type

Tags: c++, reverse-iterator

I'm trying to erase a particular item of a list from the reverse position using reverse_iterator.But an compilation error occurred in stl_iterator.h header file.

## I'm trying to do...

here input[] is an integer array.

```
 list<int>:: reverse_iterator it = l.rbegin()+ input[j];
                    l.erase( std::next(it).base() );
```

## error showing at stl_iterator.h file...

```
 reverse_iterator
      operator+(difference_type __n) const
      { return reverse_iterator(current - __n); }
```

I need to erase an particular item starting from back/end of that list.This is only for optimization or to reduce time complexity.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)?

Comment: iterator + N takes O(N) in std::list. Where is the optimization?

Comment: @Shloim , I didn't give the complete code sir. Though it's O(n) but it is helping me by doing more tasks simultaneously.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I tried with std:: advance but I can't. That's why I'm looking for the solution.

Comment: `std::next(l.rbegin(), input[j])`?

Comment: @cpplearner sir, This time no compilation error but it's not deleting the actual one. I don't even know the functionality of  std::next(l.rbegin(), input[j]). How do it delete from the list ? Would you please elaborate ?

Comment: _"I didn't give the complete code sir."_ -- yes, that is one of the problems with the way this question is asked. Providing a [mcve] (emphasis on "complete") would make it much easier to understand the question. The text of the error message would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only random access iterators support `operator+`. A list iterator is not random access iterator. To advance a non-random access iterator, you can use `std::advance` or `std::next`. Like so:

```
std::next(l.rbegin(), input[j])
```